# Cordova build problems after import google play service

Tags: cordova, google-play-services, phonegap-build

After the new update of the admob SDK now we need to import the google play service project to our projects to monetize and show ads in our apps. I am creating an app with Apache Cordova/ Phonegap and I created the android project with it and everything was fine. Then I opened my android project that cordova generated and import the google play service lib project and put all the native code I needed to show ads, then...GREAT! Works fine, tested on emulator, NICE, device, EVEN BETTER! But now when I updated my code on /www folder of cordova and try to run the command: 
`cordova build android`

I always get a build error, so everytime I need to update my code and update the android project I need to remove all the references and codes of google play service I insert at the native android project generate by cordova, run the build command and then add everything again, this is a little bit boring, somebody have already pass through this? Somebody have a better solution?
The error I got is this:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/matheus/Development/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: Invalid file: /Users/matheus/Development/google-play-services_lib/build.xml

Total time: 1 second
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/matheus/Development/phonegap_projects/TabFipeFree/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/matheus/Development/phonegap_projects/TabFipeFree/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
You can also use [this](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/google-play-services) plugin OR you can add this line in your `plugin.xml` to add this plugin as dependency.

```
<dependency id="com.google.playservices" />
```

Follow these steps to solve the problem:

1. First copy the whole google-play-services_lib folder from `ANDROID_SDK_PATH\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\` to your project root directory.(i.e. platform/android)
2. copy build.xml, local.properties & project.properties files from your `project_root_folder/Cordova` lib folder to `google-play-services_lib` folder.
3. Change the `project.properties` file's project target to the right target (i.e. android 19).
4. Open the `project.properties` from your Project Root folder and change reference 2 like this :

   android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib

   target=android-19

   android.library.reference.2=google-play-services_lib
5. Goto the `google-play-services` folder in your project and run :

   `android update project -p .` (don't forget dot)
6. Then run following commands:

   ant debug

   ant release
7. If you get any error then first run '`ant clean debug`' then follow step 6.
8. Now you can run cordova build android OR if you are using ionic then ionic build android.

Comment: libproject does not exist

Answer (score 1):

remove com.google.playservices plugin 
and add the plugin via this command
cordova plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/google-play-services.git