# PushPlugin register goes to errorhandler showing 'Class not found' with cordova 4.0.0 for android platform

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm building a hybrid app using Cordova (version 4.0.0) for Android.

I have added PushPlugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) to the project. While registering it goes to errorhandler and displays 'Class not found'.

I have tried various suggestion like

- Added plugin reference in xml. Actually plugin reference is already there in config.xml file.
- Directly install plugin using CLI
  (tried cordova plugin add
  https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git as well as cordova
  plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin)
- Create a new project etc.
- PushNotification.js is added in html (`<script type="text/javascript"
  src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>`) and is located in `www/js/`

But still I'm getting the same message 'Class not found'

I have installed supporting plugins like device, file, media that are used by PushPlugin

Please advice if anyone has a solution for this issue.

**Code sample:**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var pushNotification;
function onDeviceReady() {
    //Push notification
    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"xxxxxxxxxx", "ecb":"onNotification"});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this working by adding **google play service** library to my project

Steps to follow:

- Copy google-play-services_lib folder from `ANDROID SDK
  /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/` to your projects
  `myproject/platform/android` folder
- Copy **build.xml**, **local.properties** &
  **project.properties** files from your `myproject/platforms/android/CordovaLib` folder to `myproject/platforms/android/google-play-services_lib` folder
- Open
  **project.properties** file in `myproject/platforms/android/google-play-services_lib` folder
- Check if project target android 19 i.e. target=android-19, if not change it to
  `target=android-19`
- Open the **project.properties** from `myproject/platform/android` folder and add reference 2 like Following, 
  `target=android-19
  android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
  android.library.reference.2=google-play-services_lib`
- In CLI, goto the google-play-services_lib folder in your project and run

  `android update project -p .`
- Followed by,
  `ant debug
  ant release`
- If you get any error then first run `ant clean debug` then again run 
  `ant debug
  ant release`
- In CLI, goto `myproject/` and build the project using `cordova build android`

Got this information from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976066/cordova-build-problems-after-import-google-play-service), thought this would be helpful for others who have similar issue.

Comment: What about gradle instead ant?

Comment: i tried to run `android update project -p` . but i am getting `Error: Argument 'project' is not recognized` in CLI.