# Add google play service in MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am creating one hybrid application in MobileFirst. In mymobileFirst project I need to add Google play service library.

In Cordova they will do like this :

[PushPlugin register goes to errorhandler showing 'Class not found' with cordova 4.0.0 for android platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165842/pushplugin-register-goes-to-errorhandler-showing-class-not-found-with-cordova).

How can I do these steps in MobileFirst Project?

Is it possible to add Google Play Service in MobileFirst Project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to google a bit... the following user documentation topic is then found: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_adding_google_play_services.html